# Is memcached worth running on only one server?

Tags: wordpress, caching, memcached, mediatemple

I'm running a dv server at MediaTemple with 4 Gigs of RAM, and I'm just getting into looking at using memcached for my large Wordpress install. I understand that even though memcached is primarily designed to be used with a multiple-server setup, it can be used on only one machine - i.e., one server that is running both the cached website and memcached.

But my question is: Is it worth the trouble to run it on a single server? If I just configure the database caching on the W3 Total Cache Wordpress plugin, would that pretty much have the same effect as configuring memcached to run on the same server as my WP install? My thanks in advance for any insight you can share --

Comment: Yes. Memcached key/value fetching is usually faster than computing the key/value from any other source like code/database. Doesn't matter if memcached is distributed or not. Distribution is mainly a capacity and availability thing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Memcached is great to run on single servers - but it especially excels when sharing cache results between clusters, speeding up each host as well as the cluster as a whole by eliminating much of the processing and look-ups cluster-wide.

Running Memcached with W3 Total Cache works brilliantly, it caches tons of stuff automatically as well as giving you the ability to directly store the WP database cache and object cache there too.

However with WordPress and single server installs I would maybe suggest you use a php accelerator instead, something like [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php).

APC is primarily an opcode cache designed to speed up php execution by pre-compiling it and serving up the bytecode from a shared memory cache. It also gives you the ability to store keyed data (the database cache and object cache using W3 Total Cache) just the same as memcached.

Comment: I realise this answer is a bit old, and while the first part is mostly correct, it should be noted that there's no APC any more. Zend Optimizer is built into php now. As far as I understand it (correct me if I'm wrong!) but Opcache is the replacement for APC after php 5.4.

Comment: @digitaltoast you're correct about the replacement and no APC in php 5.5. However with this question referencing the W3 Total Cache plugin specifically it was worth mentioning APC because the plugin uses it at the application level as an object cache. Zend Optimizer can't be used as an object cache in the same way (a package called APCu exists and is a drop-in replacement for ACP as an object cache now the Opcache in built-in). Perhaps I should rewrite this answer and provide more up-to-date info but I think that as an answer to the question at the time it was asked it is sufficient.